# Problem with WPF Setup Program Installation Path

Tags: wpf, setup-project, program-files

I have a Program Setup project in my solution that should install my program to the default location:

[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]

However, this is not working and the installer is dumping all of the project files into my C: drive during installation without creating any folders at all. Even the installer says the files will be installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)\blah\blah", but they aren't. I double-checked I have values set for manufacturer and product name that don't include any special characters besides space.

I followed this tutorial step by step to get where I am:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/walkthrough-deploying-your-program-cpp?view=vs-2019

Any ideas on what could be causing my installation files to be placed in the C: drive?

I will say, my project runs correctly when running from the C drive, so the installation is technically working, it's just failing to create the program files folders and place the installation files in the correct location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue has to do with permissions on the computer. The files install to the correct directory when the installer is ran from the downloads folder.

I still find it odd that the installer dumps files into the C root drive instead of aborting the task, but at least I know now you can avoid this issue by running installer from the downloads folder.